# Musical Fizzbuzz

Tags: fizzbuzz, audio, music, chuck

I wrote some code using [ChucK : Strongly-timed, Concurrent, and On-the-fly 
Music Programming Language](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/) and would like a review. I broke down the logic into a number of classes, all of which are shown below.

This is pretty new to me, and I would appreciate any and all constructive criticism. What the main script `fizzbuzz_run.ck` does, besides the regular FizzBuzz modulus operations, is play different chords depending on the FizzBuzz result, and throughout print the results and primary oscillator frequency.

#### Clarification

I want to clarify a few things that are specific to ChucK:

- printing statements to console: `<<< "print this" >>>;`
- The ChucK operator `=>` is a bit like your usual assignment, except reverse order. For example `42 => int theMeaningOfLifeAndEverything;` is how you would otherwise `int theMeaningOfLifeAndEverything = 42;`.
- Time and duration are handled by the ChucK VM.

[Code on Github](https://github.com/Phrancis/ChucK-Scripts)

I uploaded a video to YouTube showing what it sounds like. *(video not embedded, link opens YouTube)*

[image: youtube]

#### OscPitch.ck

```
public class OscPitch {
    this.freq => float freq;
    getSemitoneRatio() => float SEMITONE;

    // Change the pitch by N musical steps
    // @param float steps : the number of steps to change the frequency, positive or negative
    // @return float : the changed frequency
    fun float change(float steps) {  
        if (Math.isnan(steps)) {
            <<< now, ": ", steps, " is not a number" >>>;
            return freq;
        } else {
            // The semitone ratio has to be applied once for each step change
            // hence the use of Math.pow which does everything
            // in one operation, rather than having to use a loop
            return freq * Math.pow(SEMITONE, steps) => freq;
        }
    }

    // Get the ratio to apply to a frequency to go up or down one semitone
    fun float getSemitoneRatio() {
        // The ratio for a musical semitone is
        // the 12th root of 2, or approximately 1.05946309436
        // More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_root_of_two
        return Math.pow(2.0, 1.0/12.0);
    }
    // Getters and setters
    fun float getFreq() { return freq; }
    fun void setFreq(float val) { val => freq; }
}
```

#### OscChords.ck

```
// Class used to create chords.
public class OscChords {
    OscPitch oscPitch;
    this.root => float root;

    0.05 => float gain;
    0.0 => float mute;
    SawOsc I, III, V, VII;
    string currentChord;

    // initialize oscillators
    0 => I.freq;
    0 => III.freq;
    0 => V.freq;
    0 => VII.freq;
    mute => I.gain;
    mute => III.gain;
    mute => V.gain;
    mute => VII.gain;
    I   => dac;
    III => dac;
    V   => dac;
    VII => dac; 

    // Sets all chord frequencies to 0, making them inaudible.
    fun void noChord() {
        0 => I.freq;
        0 => III.freq;
        0 => V.freq;
        0 => VII.freq;
        "no chord" => currentChord;
    }

    // Creates a major chord.
    // @input float root : the root note of the chord.
    fun void major(float root) {
        root => oscPitch.freq => I.freq;
        oscPitch.change(4)    => III.freq;
        oscPitch.change(3)    => V.freq;
        0                     => VII.freq;
        "major" => currentChord;
    }
    // Creates a minor chord.
    // @input float root : the root note of the chord.
    fun void minor(float root) {
        root => oscPitch.freq => I.freq;
        oscPitch.change(3)    => III.freq;
        oscPitch.change(4)    => V.freq;
        0                     => VII.freq;
        "minor" => currentChord;
    }
    // Creates a major7 chord.
    // @input float root : the root note of the chord.
    fun void major7(float root) {
        root => oscPitch.freq => I.freq;
        oscPitch.change(4)    => III.freq;
        oscPitch.change(3)    => V.freq;
        oscPitch.change(4)    => VII.freq;
        "major7" => currentChord;
    }
    // Sets the gain on the chord to make it audible.
    fun void play() {
        gain => I.gain;
        gain => III.gain;
        gain => V.gain;
        gain => VII.gain;
    }
    // Sets the gain on the chord to make it inaudible.
    fun void stop() {        
        mute => I.gain;
        mute => III.gain;
        mute => V.gain;
        mute => VII.gain;
    }
    // @return string : the name of the current chord.
    fun string getCurrentChord() { return currentChord; }
}
```

#### TempoMeter.ck

```
public class TempoMeter {
    this.bpm => float bpm;
    this.upper => int upper;
    this.lower => int lower;
    60 => int SECONDS_PER_MINUTE;
    // default values
    1::second => dur beat;
    4::beat => dur measure;

    // Divide a minute into the number of beats per minute (bpm)
    //   and return the duration of 1 beat. Default 60 bpm unless set otherwise.
    // @param float bpm : the beats per minute of the tempo
    // @return dur : the duration of a beat
    fun dur setTempo(float bpm) {
        if (Math.isnan(bpm)) {
            <<< now, ": ", bpm, " is not a number" >>>;
            return beat;
        } else {
            (SECONDS_PER_MINUTE / bpm)::second => beat;
            return beat;
        }
    }

    // Set the meter (or time signature) using traditional Western
    //   music notation. Default 4/4 unless set otherwise.
    // @param int upper : the number of beats per measure
    // @param int lower : the duration ratio (or unit) of a beat
    // @return dur : the duration of a measure
    fun dur setMeter(int upper, int lower) {
        if (Math.isnan(upper) || Math.isnan(lower)) {
            <<< now, ": ", upper, " or ", lower, " is not a number" >>>;
            return measure;
        } else {
            lower / 4 => float beatDurationRatio;
            beat * beatDurationRatio => beat;
            upper::beat => measure;
            return measure;
        }
    }

    // Getters and setters
    fun float getBpm() { return bpm; }
    fun void setBpm(float val) { val => bpm; }
    fun int getUpper() { return upper; }
    fun void setUpper(int val) { val => upper; }
    fun int getLower() { return lower; }
    fun void setLower(int val) { val => lower; }
}
```

#### fizzbuzz_run.ck

```
TempoMeter tempoMeter;
tempoMeter.setTempo(120) => dur beat;
tempoMeter.setMeter(4,4) => dur measure;

55 => float NOTE_A1;
OscPitch oscPitch;
NOTE_A1 => oscPitch.freq;
1 => int NoteAOctave;

OscChords chord;

// oscillator to digital audio controller
TriOsc fizzbuzzOsc => dac;
oscPitch.freq => chord.root => fizzbuzzOsc.freq;

// audio controls
0.1 => fizzbuzzOsc.gain;

// variables for looping
now + 12::measure => time stop;
1 => int stepCounter;

while (now < stop) {
    chord.noChord();
    <<< "-----" >>>;
    if (stepCounter % 15 == 0) {
        chord.major7(oscPitch.getFreq());
        chord.play();
        <<< "Result: ", "FizzBuzz", "| chord:", chord.getCurrentChord() >>>;
    } else if (stepCounter % 5 == 0) {
        chord.minor(oscPitch.getFreq());
        chord.play();
        <<< "Result: ", "Fizz", "| chord:", chord.getCurrentChord() >>>;
    } else if (stepCounter % 3 == 0) {
        chord.major(oscPitch.getFreq());
        chord.play();
        <<< "Result: ", "Buzz", "| chord:", chord.getCurrentChord() >>>;
    } else {
        <<< "Result: ", stepCounter >>>;
    }
    // identify reference A notes and their octave and print them
    if (Math.floor(oscPitch.getFreq() % NOTE_A1) == 0.0) {
        <<< "Reference A", NoteAOctave >>>;
        1 +=> NoteAOctave;
    }
    <<< "Osc Freq: ", oscPitch.getFreq(), "Hz" >>>;

    beat +=> now;
    chord.stop();
    oscPitch.change(1) => fizzbuzzOsc.freq;
    1 +=> stepCounter;
}
<<< "end program" >>>;
```

And just for reference, though this only pulls the classes together at runtime:

#### fizzbuzz.ck

```
// fizzbuzz.ck
// This file defines which files to add to the VM
Machine.add("OscUtils/OscPitch.ck") => int OscPitchId;
Machine.add("OscUtils/OscChords.ck") => int OscChordsId;
Machine.add("TimeUtils/TempoMeter.ck") => int TempoMeterId;
if(me.args() > 0) {
    Machine.add("fizzbuzz_run:" + me.arg(0) + ".ck");
} else {
    Machine.add("fizzbuzz_run.ck");
}
```

Comment: Small variable nitpicking: I, III, V, and VII all mean something very distinct in music. Typically when musicians see Roman numerals we think of Roman Numeral Analysis where the number would represent a chord in the key, not the intervals in the chord. Instead I suggest renaming them to Root, Third, Fifth, and Seventh.

Comment: @Dom that's a really good catch, I shall correct that!

Comment: Just when you thought you had seen all kinds of FizzBuzz variations there could ever be...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really interesting thing you've created! I've never used ChucK, but I'll try to comment on some things. I also have some, but limited music theory knowledge. If language constraints is a reason for doing something I've mentioned below, please excuse my ignorance :)

#### Semitone ratio?

I wonder why you chose to create the `getSemitoneRatio` function. It's only used to initialize the `SEMITONE` variable. Why not just remove that function and put the body as the initializer expression instead?

Additionally, I wouldn't actually call it a ratio. It's a factor.

```
// The factor to apply to a frequency to go up or down one semitone
// More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_root_of_two
Math.pow(2.0, 1.0/12.0) => float SEMITONE_FACTOR;
```

#### Dry initialization

```
// initialize oscillators
0 => I.freq;
0 => III.freq;
0 => V.freq;
0 => VII.freq;
mute => I.gain;
mute => III.gain;
mute => V.gain;
mute => VII.gain;
I   => dac;
III => dac;
V   => dac;
VII => dac; 

// Sets all chord frequencies to 0, making them inaudible.
fun void noChord() {
    0 => I.freq;
    0 => III.freq;
    0 => V.freq;
    0 => VII.freq;
    "no chord" => currentChord;
}
```

Since you already have the `noChord` function you can easily remove part of this code duplication. Just call `noChord` instead of the first four lines after the comment. The side-effect of initializing `currentChord` as well is probably just good.

#### Dry initialization 2

Another approach to this is creating a factory function for `SawOsc`. Compare the following examples.

```
SawOsc I, III, V, VII;

0 => I.freq;
0 => III.freq;
0 => V.freq;
0 => VII.freq;
mute => I.gain;
mute => III.gain;
mute => V.gain;
mute => VII.gain;
```

```
createSawOsc(0, mute) => SawOsc I;
createSawOsc(0, mute) => SawOsc III;
createSawOsc(0, mute) => SawOsc V;
createSawOsc(0, mute) => SawOsc VII;
```

#### Gain?

In `OscChord` there are two variables representing different gain levels.

```
0.05 => float gain;
0.0 => float mute;
```

It's confusing that one is just named `gain` while the other one is called `mute`. Perhaps call them `muteGain` and `playGain` to show their relationship.